# Add Class to Custom Post type list page on WordPress dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a class to each row in a WordPress custom post type list page, e.g. to add a class based on value of meta field for each post on backend:

[image]

For example: I have a feature “call enable/disable” – if the post is disabled (i.e. only viewable by certain user), the whole row should have a certain background color.

So I am looking for a solution to add a CSS class based upon meta field value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll leave you with the material to mash this up.

For one, inspect the post classes,

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

We can change them with:

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', function(){
    global $typenow; // current post type
    add_filter( 'post_class', function( $classes, $class, $postID ) {
        $classes[] = 'stack';
        return $classes;
    });
});
```

To print CSS, use:

```
add_action( 'admin_head-edit.php', function(){
    $color = 'FDFBC8';
    if( isset( $_GET['color'] ) )
        $color = $_GET['color'];
    ?>
    <style>
    tr.category-uncategorized {
        background-color: #<?php echo $color; ?> !important;
    }
    tr.stack {
        background-color: #333;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
});
```

This example looks for `?color=hexval` in the URL:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

You'll get your meta data with the `$postID` in the filter `post_class`.

Comment: [04-Aug-2020 12:48:43 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function {closure}(), 1 passed in

Comment: just a note: `$typenow`  and `$post_type` global variables both work here. Although `$typenow` is not listed [in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables#Admin_Globals) (at the time of writing).

Answer (score 1):

Just in case brasofilo´s example gives you *Missing argument* warning, you can use the filter in the old way:

```
add_filter('post_class', 'name_of_your_function');
```

Then you have to define the function. In this example, I give each row a class with the ID of the post:

```
function name_of_your_function($classes)
{
    global $post;   
    $classes[] = 'post-id-' . $post->ID;
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Why does this ever create a "too few arguments error" if the docs say this gets 3 arguments?

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_class/

Answer (score 0):

functions.php

```php
function my_post_class($classes, $class, $post_id){
    $slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', $post_id );
    $wrong_slug = false;
    if(strpos($slug, '%') !== false){
        $wrong_slug = true;
    }
    if(is_numeric(substr($slug, -1))){
        $wrong_slug = true;
    }
    if($wrong_slug){
        $classes[] = 'wrong-slug';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class', 'my_post_class', 10, 3);

function admin_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style('admin-styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/admin.css');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_style');
```

admin.css

```css
tr.wrong-slug th, tr.wrong-slug td {
  background-color: #FFCC99;
}
```